increase max_seq_len_ for llama3.2-1b android
I am using executors to run a llama3.2-1b locally, on an android phone.
To be able to use a context I need to add the previous conversation to the prompt but this leads to get over 128 seq_len, as set by default.
Tried to change that in Executorch and recompile but did not worked, I still receive the 128 length error.
Any chance someone did that and can support?
Thanks
